# How to change SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey from code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I can change the program's `FocusVisualStyle` with this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleA}" />
```

I want to give users an option to change it to a different style, but this doesn't work with an error that it is read-only:

```
SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["StyleB"];
```

How can I change it to a different style from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FocusVisualStyleKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.focusvisualstylekey?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property is defined on the type [`SystemParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). What you do in your XAML code is create a new style in a `ResourceDictionary` with a **key** (`x:Key`) that is equivalent to the value of the [`FocusVisualStyleKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.focusvisualstylekey?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property. You **do not assign a new value** to this property, like shown in your code.

The equivalent in code-behind is adding a style to a resource dictionary with this key. In this example the application resource dictionary, but it applies to any other dictionary, too.

```
Application.Current.Resources[SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey] = Application.Current.Resources["StyleB"];
```